# How to handle nonce of two consecutive blockchain transactions using ethers?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm working on a NestJS project and I have this function on my service:

```
async activateCompany(data: CompanyActivateRequest): Promise<void> {
    (...)
    await this.blockchain.addController(newWallet.address);
    await this.blockchain.increaseAllowance(newWallet.address,data.monthlyBalance);
    (...)
}
```

This is my `addController` function

```
async addController(walletAddress: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY,this._provider);
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, this._abi, wallet);
        await contract.addController(walletAddress);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(['blockchain-error']);
    }
}
```

This is my `increaseAllowance` function

```
async increaseAllowance(walletAddress: string, amount: number, increaseNonce: boolean): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY, this._provider);
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, this._abi, wallet);
        await contract.increaseAllowance(walletAddress, amount);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(['blockchain-error']);
    }
}
```

I'm having issues with nonce, mainly with nonce beeing to low. How I can properly handle it?

I'm using hardhat to run a blockchain locally.

I tried passing a boolean to each function and when it's `true` adding 1 to the current nonce but this does not work well with multiple transactions being done at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to make this work reliably:

#### Wait for the transactions to mine

In `ethers`, a method call like that will result in a `TransactionResponse`. This transaction response will contain a `hash` of the transaction that has now been submitted to the chain.

Once submitted, you need to `wait()` for the transaction to mine - depending on the blockchain and a carefully chosen balance of speed and security [*], you have to wait for this transaction to appear in a block:

```js
const response: TransactionResponse = await contract.increaseAllowance(walletAddress, amount)

// The NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS is an optional parameter
// and stands for the number of blocks that need to be "built"
// on top of the block with your transaction
//
// The higher the number, the less likely it is that
// your transaction will disappear from the blockchain
// by the mechanism of reorgs
//
// The lower the number, the faster this function will execute
const receipt: TransactionReceipt = await response.wait(NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS)
```

#### Account for parallel execution

In general, if your server wallet wants to serve a lot of users in parallel, you will need to order your transactions somehow otherwise the nonce issues will be inevitable.

The first option here is to create a job queue that will handle the transaction submission. There are several options there, depending on your budget and service complexity you might want to try something like `bull` backed by `redis`, or a much simpler yet less sturdy `fastq`.

The second option is to have a service that will act as a ticketing machine, serving nonces to the web server request handlers.

My answer is getting long, hope it's been at least a little helpful :)